# using 1's in the arrays to make a shape like '+' using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Numpy Three Four Five Dimensional Array in Python

Input 1: `3`

Output 1:

```
[[0 1 0]

 [1 1 1]

 [0 1 0]]
```

Input 2:`5`

Output 1:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]

 [0 0 1 0 0]

 [1 1 1 1 1]

 [0 0 1 0 0]

 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Notice that the *1s* in the arrays make a shape like *+*.

My logic is shown below

```
a=np.zeros((n,n),dtype='int')
a[-3,:] = 1
a[:,-3] = 1 print(a)
```

This logic is only working for five dimensional array but not for three dimensional array.

can someone assist me to get the expected output for both three and five dimensional array using `np.zeros` & integer division `//`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, `n//2 = 3` when `n=5`. So, that's the solution to your question as see here:

```
import numpy as np

def create_plus_matrix(n):
    a = np.zeros((n,n),dtype='int')
    a[-n//2,:] = 1
    a[:,-n//2] = 1
    return a
```

So, let's try it out:

```
>>> create_plus_matrix(3)
[[0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 1 0]]

>> create_plus_matrix(5)
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
import numpy as np

def plus(size):
    a = np.zeros([size,size], dtype = int)
    a[int(size/2)] = np.ones(size)
    for i in a:
        i[int(size/2)] = 1
    return a

print(plus(3)) //3 is the size
//Output
[[0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 1 0]]
```